# Angular-Route is not working.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, routes, ngroute

i am learning angularJS.i was trying implement code from a tutorial video to display a view on a html page using Route,but apparently i am stucked,although im doing exact same as the tutor is showing in the tutorial but i have no clue why it is not working ,i have searched on the internet but invain,please anyone pointout my mistake.here is my code

**Index.html**

```
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
     <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="js/angularRoute.js"></script>
     <script src="App/Myapp.js"></script>
     <script src="App/CustomerController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**App/MyApp.js**

```
var App=angular.module('App',['ngRoute']);

App.config(function($routeprovider)
          {
   $routeprovider
       .when('/',{
       controller:'CustomerController',
       templateUrl:'App/views/customers.html'
   })
   .otherwise({ redirectTo:'/'});

});
```

**views/customers.html**

```
  <div class="heading">
        <h1>Customers List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="filterBox">
    Filter:<input type="text" ng-model="CustomerFilter.name"/>
    </div>
    <table>
        <th ng-click="sorter='CustomerID';reverse=!reverse">ID</th>
        <th ng-click="sorter='name';reverse=!reverse">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="sorter='city';reverse=!reverse">City</th>
        <th ng-click="sorter='total_orders';reverse=!reverse">Total          Orders</th>
         <th ng-click="sorter='date';reverse=!reverse">Date of last  Order</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers   |filter:CustomerFilter|orderBy:sorter:reverse">
        <td>{{ cust.CustomerID }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.name|uppercase }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.city |lowercase}}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.total_orders|currency:'Rs' }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.date|date:'longDate' }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <span> Total Customers:{{customers.length}}</span>
```

I have Controller named CustomerController which i have not pasted here because beacuase it will be too large to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo, dont forget to write the p in capital

```
$routeProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect it's a URL error. Just because if your app.js is inside the App folder then you don't need to have "App" in your URLs unless you have an app/app/views folder layout.

In app.js your templateurl should just be 'views/customers.html'

You can also check your index.html. Do you have your controllers in app? Or within a scripts folder or somethign similar?

Comment: i have eidited my url several times but invain,my controller is in the same file where MyApp.js is

Comment: Yeah, my projects are set up differently, lead me down the wrong path.

By the way, presuming your typo was on '$routeprovider' then that should have produced an error message in your browsers console (Like "Unknown provider: $routeprovider") which would have sped up your bug hunt.

Post an answer to your own question, rather than leaving it unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

1: Ok, the problem is u don't have controller in ur customer.html page u need to tell ur partial view about the controller. U can simply wrap ur entire page between div tag with controller like below.

```
<div controller="CustomerController>
// ur data of customer.html page goes here
</div>
```

2: Its better to declare your config like this there won't be any problem  in your app when you minify it.

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider)
{
     // routerProvider goes here
}]);
```

Comment: if we have to refer controller in the view then why we refer the controller in the route first place?

Comment: please tell me what exactly is the error you are getting in console ??

Comment: please show me where is your controller ? i mean show me the code

Comment: nevermind i have finally figured out the problem it was just a typo,my bad .